# Yii ajaxbutton : How to get $(this) in success callback function?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

```
CHtml::ajaxButton('vote',Yii::app()->createUrl('land/Ajax'),
        array(
              'type'=>'POST',
              'data'=> 'js:{"id": '.$post->id.'}', 
              'success'=>'js:function(e){
                      console.log($(this));     // I want to control this button's silblings
                      $("input.ajaxsubmit").prop("disabled", true);
               }',
              'error'=>'js:function(e){ console.log(e); }',    
        ),
       array('class'=>'btn btn-large ajaxsubmit'));
```

I can't get button itself in success function, because this point to xhr object.
How can I pass button to success function?
CHtml::ajaxButton has no other options.

Comment: Why do you need $this? Can you explain your goal further? Maybe there are some other solutions for your goal.

Comment: i need to control the button's siblings in success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access button itself inside success event, even if you use normal button instead of yii ajaxButton. I think one workaround for this problem is to **assign an id to the button** and then access button's siblings with it's id:

```
CHtml::ajaxButton('vote',Yii::app()->createUrl('land/Ajax'),
    array(
          'type'=>'POST',
          'data'=> 'js:{"id": '.$post->id.'}', 
          'success'=>'js:function(e){    

                 //You can access to button with $("#voteButton")
           }',
          'error'=>'js:function(e){ console.log(e); }',    
    ),
   array('class'=>'btn btn-large ajaxsubmit', 'id'=>'voteButton'));
```